why instance[key] type is never?
this is my code. why this.settingData[key] type is never?
enum InlineEnum {
    auto,
    manual,
    close
}
interface DataType {
    inlineType: InlineEnum;
    localCodeRepo: boolean;
}
class Cla {
    private settingData: DataType = {
        inlineType: InlineEnum.auto,
        localCodeRepo: false
    }
    setConfig(key: keyof DataType, value: InlineEnum | boolean) {
        this.settingData[key] = value;
    }
}


Type 'boolean | InlineEnum' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) (property) Cla.settingData: DataType

I have tried deleting 'inlineType' from settingData and there should be no such issue. It seems to be caused by 'enum'. Can anyone know why?

When you read this.settingData[key], you get the union of types. But if you want to assign a value to this.settingData[key], it must be an intersection of all potential types, hence never in this case.

Because you don't know which key it is, so you don't know wether it is InlineEnum or boolean. Assigning a InlineEnum | boolean to one of the field in DataType makes no sense, because there are no fields in DataType with type InlineEnum | boolean. There is only a field of InlineEnum and a feild of boolean. You have to check which field it is before you can assign something to it. Otherwise what happen when your value is an InlineEnum and you assign it to localCodeRepo? That doesn't work.
You can type your function like this instead:
setConfig<T extends keyof DataType>(key: T, value: DataType[T]) {
    this.settingData[key] = value;
}

